# Finding $\max_{||x||_2=1} \min_i |(Ax)_i|$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Let us define for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$$M(x)=\min_i|x_i|$$

Is there a way to solve the following optimization problem:

$$\max_{||x||_2=1}M(Ax)$$

for a given $A$?

Comment: Is $A$ square or rectangular? Also, is its other dimension $m$ very large? The problem can be turned into $2^m$ easy quadratic programming tasks, but if $2^m$ is outrageously large, this isn't going to work...

Comment: @127.0.9.6: Thanks, I'd like to hear your suggestion. $A$ is rectangular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to minimizing $\|x\|_2^2$ (sum of squares) over the region $\{x : M(Ax)\ge 1\}$. Unfortunately this region is not convex or even connected in general. But it can be written as the union of $2^m$ convex regions where $m$ is the number of rows of matrix $A$. Namely, 
$$\{x : M(Ax)\ge 1\} = \bigcup_{\epsilon\in\{-1,1\}^m} \{x : \epsilon_k (Ax)_k \ge 1\}$$ where $(Ax)_k$ is the $k$th entry of vector $Ax$. So, if you can solve $2^m$ quadratic programming problems 
$$   \min    \{\|x\|_2^2 :  \forall k \ \ \epsilon_k (Ax)_k \ge 1\}$$
then just take the smallest $\|x\|_2$ out of the results.